# Python 3 'NoneType' when nativity reading in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Having issues loading in a CSV using native Python 3.6 and console is returning `TypeError: 'NoneType'object is not iterable` .

the CSV contains 2 columns which are department_id(int) and department(string).

Since this is a type error I'm hoping it's something easy, but I'm sleep deprived and I just need this to work. Here is my code for reading in the CSV. Any help would be appreciated as I feel this should be an easy fix (maybe).

```
#write function to create dict of department and within each a dict of # of count of purchase and number of first orders 
def get_department_entry(departments, line):


   data = line.strip().split(',')

   if len(data) == 2:   
      # create a dictionary entry 
      # allows us to reference the product info using product id
      # we also create a "metrics" : { "request_count": "0", "number_of_first_orders" : "0" } which 
      # will hold our metric information 
      department_info = {"department_id": data[0], "departments": data[1]}

      return departments.update({data[0] : department_info})
   else: 
      return



 #*****************************************   
departments = {}
# go through the products and populate our data structure
with open("departments.csv", encoding = 'utf-8') as file_info:
#   # skip the header
   line = file_info.readline() 

   while line:
      line = file_info.readline()
      print(line)
      departments = get_department_entry(departments, line)
for entry in departments:
#   go through all the products and output the metrics   
     print(departments[entry]["department_id"], departments[entry]['department'])
 #*******************************************************
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-aa6291de102a>", line 11, in <module>
    departments = get_department_entry(departments, line)

  File "<ipython-input-23-11dd6139f61e>", line 13, in get_department_entry
    return departments.update({data[0] : department_info})

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Updated the post after suggestions and posted new traceback error. Not sure why it's showing up as NoneType... If I had to guess it's the way the dict is placed or ```return departments.update({data[0] : department_info})``` is wrong (mainly the data[0]

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
while line:
    line = file_info.readline()
    print(line)
    department = get_department_entry(departments, line)
    if department:
        departments.update(department)
```

Comment: you return none when logic goes to else part so your dict get updated and results in an errror, i have updated the logic checkit out

Answer (score 0):

In 'get_department_entry' method, you've written

```
if len(data) == 3:
```

This will always return false, as number of columns is 2. Hence, it will return None.

That's why you are getting this error.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Even after setting it ==2 and changing data I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You should 0 and 1 index instead of 1 and 2!!

Comment: Done. Getting weird new traceback error now. (updated post)

Comment: I have a feeling it's a problem with "return departments.update({data[0] : department_info})" but I don't know what else to put instead of data[0] @pzk

Comment: There are few mistakes in your code 1. return departments.update({data[0] : department_info}) will return None as dictionary update returns None, so first you need to update it one line, then return departments in next line. 2. In else also you need to return departments 3. Somewhere you are using 'department' as key instead of 'departments'